# Delete all but the 2 latest reference period (varchar) rows per selected variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Good day,

First of all, I did some research and tried to find the solution based on what I found, but nothing seems to work :-(

So I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp.tblKeepLastRefPeriod_MC
(
  SurveyCodeId            char(2) NULL,
  SurveyGroupCodeId       int NULL,
  ReferencePeriod         varchar(6) NULL,
  QuestionnaireTypeCodeId varchar(4) NULL
);
```

With the following data:

[image]

I want to clean the table each time I execute the program to keep only the 2 latest ReferencePeriod per SurveyCodeId, SurveyGroupCodeId.  The output should look like this :

[image]

I tried the following for the select part, where the rank number should be grouped by SurveyCodeId, SurveyGroupCodeId, ReferencePeriod...  actually I tried several option, which doesn't work at all !!

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReferencePeriod
     ORDER BY ReferencePeriod DESC) AS RankFromBack
   FROM Temp.tblKeepLastRefPeriod_MC
   WHERE SurveyCodeId = '09') 
   AS DataToBeDeleted
WHERE DataToBeDeleted.RankFromBack > 2;
```

or

```
WITH e AS (  SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReferencePeriod ORDER BY
       SurveyCodeId, SurveyGroupCodeId, ReferencePeriod DESC) AS Recency
      FROM [Temp].[tblKeepLastRefPeriod_MC]) 
SELECT * 
FROM e 
WHERE Recency = 2
```

Can somebody please help me solve this problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time :-)
Mylene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be great to understand what "doesn't work at all!" means, but I think what you want is `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT
    SurveyCodeId, SurveyGroupCodeId, ReferencePeriod, QuestionnaireTypeCodeId,
    dr = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SurveyCodeId, SurveyGroupCodeId 
                            ORDER BY ReferencePeriod DESC)
  FROM Temp.tblKeepLastRefPeriod_MC
)
DELETE x WHERE dr > 2;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ed536ed0300714f7a7cc2bc26dbdb72)

(Please use that form of CREATE TABLE / INSERT sample data, instead of screenshots.)

Comment: Yep !!  This is exactly what I was looking for!
Thank you :-)